# Add same key and values while for loop in python dictionnary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am a python beginner and I am working on a small project but I can't get the output wanted.

This is the entry value that I have, I have to keep only the email's and associate them with the project without duplicated values. 
This my entry:

```
my_dictionnary = [
    {
        "email": ["email1", "email2"],
        "project":"projet1",
        "project_name":"Project1"
    },
    {
        "email": ["email1", "email2"],
        "project":"projet2",
        "project_name":"Project2"

    },
    {
        "email": ["email2"],
        "project":"projet3",
        "project_name":"Project3"

    }
]
```

I would like to create the ouput as follows:

```
my_dictionnary_parsed = {
    "email2": ["projet1", "projet2", "projet3"],
    "email1": ["projet1", "projet2"]
}
```

I have the following function:

```
def formating_email(list_of_email):
    dictionnary={}
        for email_data in list_of_email_data:
            for cp in email_data['cp_related']:
                print(cp,email_data['ticket_related_project'])
                dictionnary[cp] = email_data
```

But the values keep overriding...

Comment: Is `my_dictionnary` python code? It has invalid syntax for python or JSON.

Comment: You should post **valid** code for explaining your situation. The second code block(`my_dictionnary_parsed`) is invalid, too.

Comment: I can see a lot of typos here. Is this actually the code you're trying to run?

Comment: Sorry I corrected the typo errors

Comment: Yes I am trying to run this code but I can't get an output like my_dictionnary_parsed, I understoodd that assigning data of the dictionnary while the for loop is overiding the data, but I don't know how to get the correct output...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have correct dictionary structure, because the current one is incorrect, you are directly setting the `dictionnary[cp] = email_data`. You should instead append because it is a list.

Also, do not name your variables as `dictionnary`. Give them some valid names that correspond to their functionality, such as `projects_per_email` or anything else.

```
def formating_email(list_of_email):
    dictionnary={}
        for email_data in list_of_email_data:
            for cp in email_data['cp_related']:
                print(cp,email_data['ticket_related_project'])
                if dictionnary.get(cp) == None:
                    dictionnary[cp] = [email_data]
                else:
                    dictionnary[cp].append(email_data)
```

Comment: Did it work, because I think there may be some problem with the namings too..

Comment: Yes thank you very much sir, it worked perfectly and thank you very much for the advices you gave me on my developping pratices :))))
I wish you a wonderful day :)))

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict

new_dict=defaultdict(list)

for d in my_dictionnary:
    proj_name=d['project']
    for email in d['email']:
        new_dict['email'].append(proj_name)
```

---

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'email1': ['projet1', 'projet2'],
             'email2': ['projet1', 'projet2', 'projet3']})
```

Comment: It was really helpful thank you very much sir for helping me :) have a nice day sir  :) @Ch3steR